# Loading another image with same function unloads other one

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function loadSlide(url, zIndex, initLeft){
        slide = $("<img />").attr("src", url).on("load", function() {
            if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
                console.log("broken image!");
            } else {
                $("#my_slider").append(slide);
                slide.css({
                    "z-index": zIndex, 
                    "left": initLeft
                });
            }
        });    
    }

    loadSlide("img/man_slide1.png", 100, "0vw");
    loadSlide("img/man_slide2.png", 99, "0vw");
});
```

I can't wrap my head around this problem. As you can see I wish to call the same function multiple times to load several images. But only the last one loads in my browser (and checked in Inspector).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This: `$("<img />")` is wrong. It should be `$("img")`.

Comment: I know what you mean, and I tested it, but now there's no img tag created. That's why it's `$("<img />")`

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out:

`slide = $("<img />").attr("src", url).on("load", function() {`

needed to be NOT a global variable, but local to the functions' scope, like so:

`var slide = $("<img />").attr("src", url).on("load", function() {`

edit, for clarity, I put the function into a variable as well:

```
$( document ).ready(function() { 
        $.loadImage = function loadSlide(url, zIndex, initLeft, className){
        var slide = $("<img />").attr("src", url)
        .on("load", function() {
            if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
                console.log("broken image!");
            } else {
                $("#my_slider").append(slide);
                slide.css({"z-index": zIndex, "left": initLeft}).addClass(className);
            }
        });    
    }
    $.loadImage("img/man_slide1.png", 100, "-100vw", "slide1_1");
    $.loadImage("img/man_slide2.png", 99, "-100vw", "slide2_1");
    $.loadImage("img/man_slide3.png", 98, "-100vw", "slide3_1");
    $.loadImage("img/man_slide4.png", 97, "100vw", "slide4_1");  
});
```

Comment: So, you just missed a `var` ?

Comment: Yes, apparently so.